# Запуск эмулятора Android Studio на процессоре AMD

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор

При нажатии запуска(run) эмулятора, всплывает окошечко с требованием установить HAXM. Когда проц у меня AMD, интеловские пакеты не поддерживаются.

[image]

Тут я показал установленный пакет Эмулятор Гипервизор для AMD(в ролике видел, если не интел значит этот пакет качаем, так говорилось)

[image]

А это то самое мерзкое окно которое всплывает после запуска эмулятора.

Все источники рекомендуют производить операцию включения виртуализации в BIOS а так же какие-то танцы с включением и выключением Hyper-V.

[image]

Вот как-то я пытался мансовать. На скрине приложение показывает что виртуализация отключена. Хотя я как раз таки её включал, странно, ну да ладно. И в компонентах напротив Hyper-V стоит галочка

[image].

И вот при таких условиях Android Studio запрашивает шахматы. Как надо всё расставить что бы заработало?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что установочный пакет, указанный в SDK Tools требует установки. Он просто скачивается в папку, где лежит ***AndroidSDK\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver***, но сам не устанавливается.
Нужно вручную запустить ***silent_install.bat*** от имени Администратора.
Команда разработки говорит, что это пока временное решение. Почитать про это нововведение можно тут:
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html

Благодаря AMD Hypervisor эмуляция будет запускаться с хардверным ускорением ЦПУ, не нужно включать Hyper-V / WHPX (а значит, вы сможете запускать другие виртуальные машины, типа VirtualBox, т.к. раньше такое было невозможно).

Можно вручную скачать вот здесь:
https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors

Таким образом, идеальная конфигурация, когда Hyper-V, Windows Hypervisor Platform и Windows Sandbox (Windows 10) - **отключены**.
При этом виртуализация в БИОС должна быть включена (**Enabled**). Называться этот пункт должен Virtualization/AMD-V или SVM (Secure Virtual Machines).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218262/unable-to-install-android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processor

Я решил проблему. Обратите внимание на последний комментарий про антивирус Avast. Я отключил "Включить виртуализацию с аппаратной поддержкой" и все сразу установилось. Теперь я могу работать с эмулятором андроид на Flutter через Visual Studio.
А так я сделал все те же ходы, что и вы. Только дополнительно отключил функцию в Avast.
Удачи.

Answer (score -1):

Обратите внимание на Эмулятор Гипервизор для AMD в SDK Tools. Там в скобочках указанно, что загружается установочник. Перейдите в папку, куда он его скачает(у меня это был C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver) и  запустите от имени админа расположенный там батник siulent_install. После этого список эмуляторов должен перестать предлагать поставить HAXM и виртуалки должны запускаться